# Collecting logs with fluentbit to loki - Indexing custom labels

Tags: logging, fluent-bit, grafana-loki

I wanted to check the following with you:

I have this kind of YAML manifest, it is a pod that is triggered when events on my app take place:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-10T12:13:46Z"
  generateName: job-1bb229b1-aa15-4349-b676-ad9cf840b44a-
  labels:
    app: CalculationPod
    calculationId: "1467"
    controller-uid: 75d707d6-aab6-446d-9726-7ffafde29191
    job-name: job-1bb229b1-aa15-4349-b676-ad9cf840b44a
  name: job-1bb229b1-aa15-4349-b676-ad9cf840b44a-h4pj
```

I am using fluent-bit (from Loki stack) to collect logs in my k8s cluster.
Actually, I want to index the `calculationId: "1467"` label I have in the pod, to make it appear  in grafana-Loki such as app: `CalculationPod` is right now in the picture:

[image]

So this is my output Loki plugin configuration on fluetbit configmap side:

I am trying to get the value of `calculationId` label and pass it as a parameter to the set of labels at Labels parameter in this way:

```
[Output] 
        Name grafana-loki
        Match *
        Url http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
        TenantID ""
        BatchWait 1
        BatchSize 1048576
        Labels {job="fluent-bit",calculationId="$calculationId"} # SEE HERE
        RemoveKeys kubernetes,stream
        AutoKubernetesLabels false
        LabelMapPath /fluent-bit/etc/labelmap.json
        LineFormat json
        LogLevel warn
```

But I couldn’t see nothing has changed in my Loki UI.
I am not sure if that is the correct way to add new labels to be indexed I am checking this https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/loki#labels

Any help will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get the `calculationId` label and its value by adding it to the kubernetes labels JSON information is being referenced and that the kubernetes filter call. You can see more about this [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/fluentbit/#labelmappath)

So the entire `configmap/loki-fluent-bit-loki` configuration file is this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  fluent-bit.conf: |-
    [SERVICE]
        HTTP_Server    On
        HTTP_Listen    0.0.0.0
        HTTP_PORT      2020
        Flush          1
        Daemon         Off
        Log_Level      warn
        Parsers_File   parsers.conf
    [INPUT]
        Name           tail
        Tag            kube.*
        Path           /var/log/containers/*.log
        Parser         docker
        DB             /run/fluent-bit/flb_kube.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit  1000MB
    [FILTER]
        Name           kubernetes
        Match          kube.*
        Kube_URL       https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Merge_Log On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser Off
    [Output]
        Name grafana-loki
        Match *
        Url http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
        TenantID ""
        BatchWait 1
        BatchSize 1048576
        Labels {job="fluent-bit"}
        RemoveKeys kubernetes,stream
        AutoKubernetesLabels false
        LabelMapPath /fluent-bit/etc/labelmap.json
        LineFormat json
        LogLevel warn
  labelmap.json: |-
    {
      "kubernetes": {
        "container_name": "container",
        "host": "node",
        "labels": {
          "app": "app",
          "release": "release",
          "calculationId": "calculationId" # IT WAS ADDED HERE
        },
       "namespace_name": "namespace",
       "pod_name": "instance"
      },
      "stream": "stream"
    }
  parsers.conf: |-
    [PARSER]
        Name        docker
        Format      json
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L 
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: loki
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: monitoring
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-26T10:23:32Z"
  labels:
    app: fluent-bit-loki
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: fluent-bit-2.3.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: loki
  name: loki-fluent-bit-loki
  namespace: monitoring
```

Then I got now the `calculationId` label indexed:

[image]

I didn't try, but according to the way the loki fluentbit output plugin works, the `LabelKeys` parameter also allow me to add a custom label like my `calculationId` and get it to use it to get its log streams

The [grafana loki documentation says](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/fluentbit/#configuration-options):

> LabelKeys: Comma separated list of keys to use as stream labels. All other keys will be placed into the log line. LabelKeys is deactivated when using LabelMapPath label mapping configuration.

So According to this, `LabelKeys` should works as well, and then if I use it I wouldn't need to use the `LabelMapPath` parameter to reference in json the desired labels.

---

**IMPORTANT**

I am using here the fluent-bit collector agent that comes with the loki stack, it means [this installation approach](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/helm/#deploy-loki-stack-loki-fluent-bit-grafana-prometheus). Is opportune to highlight this is not the official fluent-bit collector, the official one is [this](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes#installing-with-helm-chart). Right now [there is a request to deprecate](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/4648) the fluent-bit grafana loki stack in favor of the official one, so will be opportune to highlight this, and think about to use the official one.

Comment: If the `calculationId` field can contain many unique values, then Loki may suffer from high memory usage because of high cardinality issues. It is better to store this field in the log messages then. See [these docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/best-practices/).